# return different result to find Factorial Trailing Zero

Tags: java, algorithm

I have below two versions of implementation, why they return different results?

**Problem statement**,

Given an integer n, return the number of trailing zeroes in n!.

**Source code in Java**,

```
public class TrailingZero {

    public static int trailingZeroes(int n) {
        int result = 0;
        int base = 5;
        while (n/base > 0) {
            result += n/base;
            base *= 5;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static int trailingZeroesV2(int n) {
        return n == 0 ? 0 : n / 5 + trailingZeroes(n / 5);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(trailingZeroes(1808548329));
        System.out.println(trailingZeroesV2(1808548329));
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think the question wants you to return the number of trailing zeros in n factorial.

Comment: In the second the recursive call should be `trailingZeroesV2`; a typo,isn't it.

Comment: @JoeC, thanks, I will post a new version to make it clear.

Comment: @Bálint, yes it is, if you have any ideas why two versions of code return different value, it will be great.

Comment: @Bálint, vote up your reply and I start a new post to make my question to be more clear, we can continue to discuss here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42756140/inconsistent-results-when-finding-factorial-trailing-zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`base` becoming multiplied by 5 got lost in the second version.

```
public static int trailingZeroesV2(int n) {
    return trailingZeroesV2(n, 5);
}

private static int trailingZeroesRec(int n, int base) {
    return n == 0 ? 0 : n / base + trailingZeroesRec(n / 5, base * 5);
}
```

(Typically a recursive function uses an extra parameter,)

The correctness of both versions I leave to your ingenuity.
It obviously uses that the number of factors of 5 in the factorial has at least the same number of factor 2. So the factors of 10 can be determined as such.

I would however consider `% 5`, modulo 5. But I will not seriously delve into your algorithm.

Comment: This should be `n / 5 + trailingZeroesRec(n / 5, base * 5)`

Comment: BTW, Joop, mark your reply as answer and I start a new post to make my question to be more clear, we can continue to discuss here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42756140/inconsistent-results-when-finding-factorial-trailing-zero

Comment: @user1952500, vote up your reply and I start a new post to make my question to be more clear, we can continue to discuss here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42756140/inconsistent-results-when-finding-factorial-trailing-zero

Comment: @LinMa replied on the other question. This is a case of integer overflow.