# inconsistent results when finding Factorial Trailing Zero

Tags: java, algorithm

Here are two versions of code I write to return the number of trailing zeroes in n!. The first version returns `452137080` for input `1808548329`, the 2nd version returns `452137076` for input `1808548329`. Wondering why there is a difference? The output from 2nd version is correct.

**Source code in Java**,

```
public class TrailingZero {
    public static int trailingZeroes(int n) {
        int result = 0;
        int base = 5;
        while (n/base > 0) {
            result += n/base;
            base *= 5;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static int trailingZeroesV2(int n) {
        return n == 0 ? 0 : n / 5 + trailingZeroesV2(n / 5);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(trailingZeroes(1808548329));
        System.out.println(trailingZeroesV2(1808548329));
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [return different result to find Factorial Trailing Zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42754047/return-different-result-to-find-factorial-trailing-zero)

Comment: (The recursive call may have been corrected. (It might help to explicitly state this and link to the previous question.)) Look at the magnitude of `base`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) in the value of `base`.

Changing your code slightly to print `n / base` and `base`:

```
public class TrailingZero {
    public static int trailingZeroes(int n) {
        int result = 0;
        int base = 5;
        while (n/base > 0) {
            System.out.println("n = " + n/base  + " base = " + base);
            result += n/base;
            base *= 5;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static int trailingZeroesV2(int n) {
        return n == 0 ? 0 : n / 5 + trailingZeroesV2(n / 5);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(trailingZeroes(1808548329));
        System.out.println(trailingZeroesV2(1808548329));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
n = 361709665 base = 5
n = 72341933 base = 25
n = 14468386 base = 125
n = 2893677 base = 625
n = 578735 base = 3125
n = 115747 base = 15625
n = 23149 base = 78125
n = 4629 base = 390625
n = 925 base = 1953125
n = 185 base = 9765625
n = 37 base = 48828125
n = 7 base = 244140625
n = 1 base = 1220703125
n = 1 base = 1808548329   <== OOPS 6103515625 overflows 32-bit integer
n = 3 base = 452807053
452137080
```

As you can see here, `base` increases to `1220703125`, when `n =`1. Then the statement `base *= 5` runs which makes it `6103515625` which is overshoots the maximum 32-bit unsigned int (`2^32`) by exactly `6103515625  - 2^32 = 1808548329`, and that is what you see as the intermediate wrong value of `b` above (`OOPS`).

On the other hand, the recursive solution only uses the value of `n` which continuously decreases. Hence there is no overflow.

The simple solution is to declare `base` as long, i.e., `long base = 5`. That will return the right value of `452137076`.

Another solution will be to modify the loop to only use `n`, similar to the recursive solution:

```
    int base = 5;
    while (n > 0) {
        result += n/base;
        n = n/base;
    }
```

Note that in problems involving factorials, overflow is a given and you may want to consider higher precision arithmetic such as [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: A shorter version of non-recursive implementation: `int result = 0; for (int i = n; i >= 5; ) result += (i /= 5); return result;`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko you are right that there are multiple shorter forms allowed. For example you could put in the initialization and update of `result` into the for statement itself. There is no improvement in time complexity, but could be (arguably) considered as increasing obscurity.

Comment: nice answer @user1952500, vote up and mark your reply as answer.